# How do I change the default download directory for pre-trained model in Keras?

Tags: pip, keras, virtualenv

According to [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/), it says that the default download directory for all Keras files is `$HOME/.keras`.  I'm using virtual environment and I want to change the default download directory of pre-trained models to a different directory. Maybe this has more to do with virtualenv than with Keras?

Comment: We can see here that the dir is hardcoded: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/data_utils.py/#L123 --- So you can't change it (unless you change keras code, which might be unsafe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation

> Signature: ResNet50(include_top=True, weights='imagenet',
>   input_tensor=None, input_shape=None, pooling=None, classes=1000)

There's no parameter to specify where to download the pre-trained model weights.

(1) What you can do is to move the file to where you want it to be after the download from your terminal using `mv` (https://www.macworld.com/article/2080814/master-the-command-line-copying-and-moving-files.html).

---

**UPDATE**: I went to check the github repo of Keras (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/resnet50.py) and found the link to the weights. For resnet:

```
WEIGHTS_PATH = 'https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.2/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5'
WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP = 'https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.2/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'
```

You can download those weights directly to your file system using whatever methods (i.e. `urllib`).

Comment: The problem is I only have limited storage permission to download it first.

Comment: @Sunil The path `~/.keras` is hardcoded but it's not necessary be a directory. It can be a symlink to a directory where you have enough space.

Comment: Thank you @YilunZhang, I was about to try it but I used the solution from phd. Symbolic link was what I needed.

Comment: Downloading the weights may be unsafe. Keras does treat them depending on the backend you're using and your data format.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the master branch of keras, you can [set the `KERAS_HOME` environment variable](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/data_utils.py#L174) to set the cache directory. If it is not set, cache directory defaults to `$HOME/.keras`.

```
export KERAS_HOME="/path/to/keras/dir"
```

Add the line to your ".bashrc" to set the variable every time you open up a new terminal.

This has not yet been released, you must use the master branch to use this feature.

Comment: I'm using keras 2.3.0-tf.  When I set KERAS_HOME to ${HOME}/Downloads/keras, keras seems to recognized it, and created keras.json file in that directory, but it doesn't cache any download data.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the model fiel *.h5 that has been downloaded via other ways into the Keras default models directory `~/keras/models`.